# MDX Calculation on SETS

Tags: set, mdx

I have an MDX query where I am using a Parent-Child hierarchy where a property on any level have a specific values.

Now I want to take create a sets, that have each of these specific values and subtract them from each other

The query I have looks like this:

```
    WITH 
    SET [OMS] AS
    {
    DESCENDANTS(
        FILTER([ReportHierarchy].[Hierarchy].MEMBERS,
            [ReportHierarchy].[Hierarchy].Properties( "Sum Code" )="OMS")
        ,,SELF)
    }
    SET [VF] as {
    DESCENDANTS(
        FILTER([ReportHierarchy].[Hierarchy].MEMBERS,
            [ReportHierarchy].[Hierarchy].Properties( "Sum Code" )="VF")
        ,,SELF)
    }
    SELECT 
{
    [Measures].[Amount],
    [Measures].[Budget Amount]
}    ON COLUMNS,
{
    [OMS],
    [VF]

}
on ROWS
    FROM 
Finance
    WHERE
[ReportHierarchy].[Hierarchy Name].&[Income and Balance]
```

which returns this result:

```
                Amount           Budget Amount
    Nettoomsætning  -126418831.1    -308192540.75
    Vareforbrug 65415924.25 159307880.45
```

Now I want to do a calulation which subtracts SET [VF] from  set [OMS]...

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you need `WITH MEMBER` to create a new item in your left-most column. This new item can be set up to calculate the value of one item minus another. Here's a similar situation from an old query I wrote years ago:

```
    WITH MEMBER [Actual Time].[MySubtraction] 
    AS '[Actual Time].[Week].[Week 5] - [Actual Time].[Week].[Week 4]', SOLVE_ORDER=80 
    SELECT {
        [Location].[All Location].[Blah Blah]
    } ON ROWS,{
        [Actual Time].[Week].members,
        [Actual Time].[MySubtraction] 
    } 
    ON COLUMNS FROM [CubeName] 
    WHERE ([Measures].[Whatever])
```

My MDX is getting rusty these days, so I have not tried to give you the exact query you need, sorry. Have a look at the documentation for `WITH MEMBER` to learn more.